# Usage of QOpenGLVertexArrayObject

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

i have a question concering VAO in QT. As supposed [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglvertexarrayobject.html), i wrote the following piece of code for initialization:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    vao.create();
    vao.bind();
    // setting up buffers
    buffer.create();
    buffer.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    buffer.bind();
    buffer.allocate(vertices.data(), 3 * vertices.size() * sizeof(float));
    vao.release();

}
```

In the painting stage, i simply do the following:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL() {
  // some other code
  vao.bind();
  if(shader_program->isLinked()) {
    shader_program->setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", p_matrix * v_matrix * m_matrix);
    // the interesting part about the buffer:
    shader_program->setAttributeBuffer("vertex", GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    shader_program->enableAttributeArray("vertex");
    // the drawing
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
    shader_program->disableAttributeArray("vertex");
  } 
  vao.release();
}
```

This works as far as i am dealing with only one VAO. But while using multiple VAO's, nothing or only one 'object' (buffer) is drawn. The code is exactly the same for each object, so the drawing is always

1. Bind VAO
2. Assign variables to the shader program
3. Draw Triangles
4. Release VAO

So the question is how to use multiple vao's including different buffers.

Comment: What is the point of downvoting this question?

Comment: m47h, did you ever find a solution to dealing with multiple VAOs or VBOs in Qt?  I'm having similar issues.

Comment: @Alchete: no, i did not. I decided to forego these Qt wrapper classes and do it 'manually'.

Answer (score 3):

You have abstracted your GLSL program class incorrectly.

Programs themselves do not store vertex array pointers and array enable/disable state, VAOs do. You need to move the code directly under the comment: " the interesting part about the buffer:" into `initializeGL (...)`, but because of the way your GLSL program class is currently setup you will need to refactor that and your VAO class as well.

Currently ***none*** of the commands in `initializeGL (...)` actually affect the state of your VAO - you are binding and unbinding the VAO with a few unrelated commands in-between (as I will explain below).

---

Note that VAOs do not explicitly store vertex buffer bindings, but array pointers are relative to whatever VBO was bound at the time the function was called. VAOs ***do however,*** store element buffer bindings (for `glDrawElements (...)`). This may become important knowledge when you re-tool your VAO class.

You also should not enable and disable arrays before and after drawing when you use VAOs, this was part of the reason VAOs were created. You bind a VAO before drawing and it takes care of enabling all of the arrays it needs and disabling the ones it does not (which should be established in your `initializeGL (...)` function).

Comment: I think i got the point. But my problem is, that the VAO class and the Shaderprogram class are provided from QT 5 and i wonder how to use them in a correct way without refactoring them.

Comment: Really? I would have expected better from Trolltech/Nokia/Whoever owns Qt now. GLSL programs do not store the states that you have to use a GLSL program object to set... having to use a GLSL program to set a VAO state is downright awful design :-\ I guess you will just have to keep that in mind, VAOs store those states so even though you use a GLSL program object to set them, you need to do them in the context of whatever VAO is currently bound.